# Data truncation when '$' or '&' is used as argument in java command line

Tags: java

I am getting data truncation when I pass '$' or '&' as part of data in my java arguments. I know that issue can be resolved by using escape character '\' before '$' but I don't understand why we are seeing this only for '$' or '&' and not for any other special characters like '@','#','%','^' or'*'

Following is my standalone test case to reproduce this error

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Input

```
java Main name=Daniel$Burgers
```

Output

```
[name=Daniel]
name=Daniel
```

Comment: As a side note, you could also solve the issue by quoting the string, e.g. `java Main name="Daniel$Burgers"`

Comment: @AlexandruSomai: I suspect using double quotes wouldn't work. Single quotes would though.

Comment: Yeah it works for single quote

Comment: The shell changes the meaning of your input.

Comment: I think that this has nothing to do with Java, but rather the shell interpreting the command string, even *before* it is passed to `java`.

Comment: @Jayan : Can you pls explain?

Comment: where are you running the program?  Daniel$Burgers becomes Daniel as $Burgers has no value

Comment: @JonSkeet I think that depends on where you try to use it. If I'm not mistaken Windows' CMD uses double quotes.

Comment: @Amongalen: The Windows command line uses '%' rather than '$' for variable substitution. I inferred from the post that the OP is using something like bash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a Java issue - it's your shell; the command line from which you're running the code. `$` is usually used for variable substitution in shells; `&` is usually used for background processes. You'd see the same using echo:

```sh
$ echo name=Daniel$Burgers
```

Output:

```
name=Daniel
```

If you put the value in single quotes, that tells the shell not to do anything special until the end of the string (another single quote):

```sh
$ echo 'name=Daniel$Burgers'
```

Output:

```
name=Daniel$Burgers
```

The same change should fix your Java invocation.